# Execute a custom URL during an ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I was trying to execute an AJAX request (file: ajax.php) and i want to trigger another custom URL from ajax.php during this AJAX call.

I tried CURL for this, but not seems to be fruitfull.

It will be really helpful if somebody can help me on this.

```
// this function is executed using ajax
private function ajax_process($page){
  if($yes){
     // execute some code
  }else{
       $ch = curl_init(); 
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.1.3/test/index.php?fnc=tobasket&aid=378442f7aa427425c741607aa3440ee8&am=1'); 
       curl_exec($ch); 
       curl_close($ch); 
  }

  // continue the process
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Arun

Comment: can you post some code and what have you tried till now?

Comment: This is the curl function   $ch = curl_init(); 
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.1.3/test/index.php?fnc=tobasket&aid=378442f7aa427425c741607aa3440ee8&am=1'); 
               curl_exec($ch); 
               curl_close($ch);

Comment: Did you set the right options for curl to get the content?

Comment: edit your question and put the code in there so that it is readable

Comment: @Guns question edited

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
// this function is executed using ajax
private function ajax_process($page){
  if($yes){
     // execute some code
  }else{
       $ch = curl_init(); 
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.1.3/test/index.php?fnc=tobasket&aid=378442f7aa427425c741607aa3440ee8&am=1'); 
       $headers = array(
          'Accept: application/json',
          'Content-Type: application/json',
       );
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
       $response = curl_exec($ch); 
       curl_close($ch); 
       var_dump($response);
  }

  // continue the process
}
```